# Only keep one div expanded

Tags: jquery

I'm using simple-expand Jquery plugin (http://sylvain-hamel.github.io/simple-expand/) it expands divs perfectly. The problem I'm having is that all the expanded divs remain open. Ideally only 1 should be opened at a time.

You can see the live version here: http://www.soft-dog.com/TES88484

I have tried the following code, but it doesn't hide the already opened ones.

```
$('.reveal').click(function () {
            // When clicked, toggle the "view" div.  $('.content').hide();
```

Comment: could you show all relevant code please?

Comment: Show all code please

Comment: You don't properly close the function on the site so it errors and will never hide anything. There is also no element on page with reveal class. To be honest I am not sure why you need a plugin for this.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show all the code (as the above comments said).

However, if you want to simply show and hide with jQuery's `show()` and `hide()` functions, then it can be as simple as:

```
$("div.toOpen").click(function() {
    $("div.toOpen").hide();
    $(this).show();
});
```

This will hide all of the divs and then open up the current one again.